# How to choose を vs は

Tags: particles

During my Japanese classes, I saw two examples really similar :

- 昨日、さとうさんは自転車で事故にあったけれども、怪我はしなかった。
- 車で事故にあうと、怪我をします。

I don't understand why for the first one, the particle before する is は, and for the second one it's を.

Comment: Does this help? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/86333/43676

Comment: A bit, but in my examples, the exclusivity nuance makes no sense for me because you are injured or not there are no other choices isn't it?

Comment: The bicycle may have been damaged but at least he didn’t get injured.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14791/9831 (See the examples in the accepted answer)