# The use of は and も with non-する verbs

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjugations

When using a する verb, it seems very intuitive to used は and も to add nuance to a statement. 起床はしたんだけれど、まだ寝ボケだった for example. Or something like 確認もしたのにやっぱり誤り見逃した. To my understanding, は and も can be used pretty freely with する-verbs. (If these two sentences are unnatural please let me know.) However, on the other hand, it seems this usage is less common or less acceptable with non-する verbs. For example　起きはしたんだけれど、まだ寝ボケだった seems to have a different, more specific meaning, such as in sayings like 入れてくれやしねぇ. Is my impression of は and も with verbs correct? I always want to use these constructions as they seem intuitive but I'm not sure if they're proper.

Comment: I meant to include this with the post, but here is an example of this conjugation with non-する verbs. It seems to have some usage so Im trying to figure out exactly how and when to use it properly. https://i.imgur.com/zQnYUtz.png From an episode of Jojo.

Comment: Partially related: [Usage of は in these sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/86333/43676)

Comment: まだ寝ボケていた sounds more natural with the verb form 寝ボケる. Between 起床はしたんだけど and 起きはしたんだけど, I would vote for the latter. This is simply a question of register.